# Setting overflow-x: hidden adds a vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

When I specify `overflow-x: hidden` on an element which overflows both horizontally and vertically, the element gets a vertical scroll bar in addition to hiding the horizontally overflowing content. I have tried adding `overflow-y: visible` and even just `overflow: visible`, to no effect.

Am I misunderstanding what these properties do? I would think that `overflow-x` should not affect the vertical overflow at all.

This has happened on every browser I've tried.

Here's a snippet which demonstrates the effect. I'm using `<pre>` tags because they're an easy way to create overflowing content, but it seems to happen with any tag.

```css
pre {
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 50px; /* We need this so they don't overlap. */
}

#x-hidden {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#y-visible {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

#visible {
  overflow: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Praesent bibendum lorem felis, sit amet sodales nunc gravida eget.
  Integer mollis quis magna quis vulputate.
  Cras aliquet convallis efficitur.
</pre>

<pre id="x-hidden">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Praesent bibendum lorem felis, sit amet sodales nunc gravida eget.
  Integer mollis quis magna quis vulputate.
  Cras aliquet convallis efficitur.
</pre>

<pre id="y-visible">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Praesent bibendum lorem felis, sit amet sodales nunc gravida eget.
  Integer mollis quis magna quis vulputate.
  Cras aliquet convallis efficitur.
</pre>

<pre id="visible">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Praesent bibendum lorem felis, sit amet sodales nunc gravida eget.
  Integer mollis quis magna quis vulputate.
  Cras aliquet convallis efficitur.
</pre>
```

The [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x) says:

> The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’.

But this makes no mention of the case when `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` is set to `hidden`, which to me implies that this combination is indeed meant to be possible.

Comment: You might want to paste some sample code at jsfiddle.net :)

Comment: x-axis = horizontal. y-axis = vertical.

Comment: I just encountered this problem. Our designers want to create graphics which "flow" off the right edge. So I allow the image to overflow the container div, but then I set overflow hidden for the full-width row to clip the image and prevent a horizontal scrollbar for the entire page. The catch is, I also have a .row::after element which creates a shadow and uses absolute positioning to push it below the row, which overflow hidden will hide. overflow-x hidden; overflow-y:visible creates a scrollbar. I'd like the x to clip, and the y to overflow without a scrollbar. Similar to the poster's issue.

Comment: @Dustin Graham The scroll bars could be showing for the div or element outside the div/element you are styling. You may have to say overflow: visible for all the elements/divs containing this element/div.

Comment: Unfortunately, I went with a nested div to clip the image with overflow hidden. Then the parent div didn't need overflow hidden, so had no scroll bars while allowing the parent div to push the .row::after element down.

Comment: oct 2022, just encountered this issue, and the answers and article linked has not any answer either. I wanted to `overflow-x-hidden` and show the Y but it added  a scroll bar. I ended up addinng `overflow-x-CLIP`. Solved it for now.

Comment: EDIT: doest work on SAFARI below v15.6 considering that a lot of people uses the oldest versions and/or can't update their Mac's because of some storage issue has no solution yet

Answer (score 45):

Check out this answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/3583023

It explains why

```
el {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

renders as

```
el {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

which usually renders the same as

```
el {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

because the `auto` value of `overflow-y` is `scroll` in most browsers.

So, in order to achieve this effect, we can't use the `overflow-x/overflow-y` properties. I've experimented with the `clip` property as a potential alternative, but no luck so far: http://jsfiddle.net/qvEq5/

Comment: what an unfortunate problem, who's answer is "you just can't". Such a shame, but thanks for showing my problem is impossible!

Answer (score 7):

Try setting your height. Either make it like 100%, or auto
check this

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsAy9/1/)

```
    height: auto;
```

Comment: This worked for me. `body { height: auto; overflow-x: hidden; }` Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that safari in some devices (ipad, iphone, not sure which it was) still allows horizontal scrolling when overflow-x is set to body. Usually i create inner div with overflow-x hidden. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697922/horizontal-scroll-mac-safari-only

Answer (score 7):

Just an hour ago I had the similar problem except the problem occurred when I had specified `overflow`'s value as `auto`. I didn't use `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`, I just needed it to fully contain my two lists that were floating on opposite ends.

What worked for me was that I changed `overflow`'s value to `hidden`. Try that. I had set the `max-width` to `100%` and instead of specifying height, I just used `overflow: hidden`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The issue is that we are trying to cut the overflow on one axis only. IE: cut off horizontal overflow with `overflow-x:hidden`, using the `overflow-y:visible` to have something hang over the edge. HOWEVER, when using this particular combination, it causes a scrollbar to show. THIS is the problem.

Comment: thats helped me solve the issue.. mite not be usable for all use cases but if you can use `max-width: 100%` that solves it. should be the selected answer in my view

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try:

```
height: auto;
width: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Should keep the element at 100px wide, and allow it to expand vertically based on its content (without scrollbars).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rUE2D/1/) shows the problem which you describe.

As yet, I don't know how to get around this, but it seems like the [spec hints to this here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x):

> The computed values of ‘`overflow-x`’ and ‘`overflow-y`’ are the same as
>   their specified values, **except that some combinations with ‘visible’
>   are not possible**: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is
>   ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’.

Answer (score 1):

Just use overflow: hidden on a wrapper div with size constraints.  Excuse my formatting in a bit of a rush today.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.hidden 
{
background-color:#00FF00;
width:100px;
height:100px;
overflow:hidden;
}
div.overflowing
{
width:300px;
height:200px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>overflow:hidden</p>
<div class="hidden">
<div class="overflowing">
You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/4PZC9/

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the display property? The overflow declaration works on block level elements!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: How is that not an answer?!

Comment: This is an auxiliary question, followed by a comment. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer will give you a few pointers on how to provide good answers.

Comment: I see...you can't explain why it isn't an answer, because it is, in fact, an answer.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you misunderstood something, I didn't unsdertood the question... or the problem is not in the overflow settings.

`Overflow: auto` will add the scrollbar only if needed (content bigger than container).
`Òverflow: visible` will add the scrollbar.
`Òverflow: hidden` will NOT add the scrollbar.

I understand that you want the x-content to be hidden, so `overflow-x: hidden`, but from your question it seems to me that don't want the vertical scrollbar to see the vertically overflowed content.

Maybe the problem is that is set a fixed height (or max-height) for the container and the content is bigger. Remove the height (or max height) and you'll avoid the vertical scrollbar.

...or as maybe I said, just didn't understood what is the desired effect.

Answer (score -3):

Try this,

```
height: auto;
overflow:hidden;
```

Cheers.

Comment: Scrollbar needs fixed height

Answer (score -7):

Reading you question... I don't see any problem...

> Whe I specify overflow-x:hidden; on an element, it adds a vertical scroll bar.

If it overflows in it's height (as you just said it does), then that's quite normal.

> I have tried adding overflow-y:visible; and even just overflow:visible, to no effect.

Well... That's normal, as you're telling it to show a vertical scrollbar, wich there already is.

As kuloir said: X = horizontal; Y = vertical.

Comment: I am not telling it to add a vertical scrollbar.  That would be overflow-y:scroll.  I am telling it to simply appear outside of its box, but it instead is adding a scrollbar.  Overflow-x:hidden is supposed to hide any content that goes out of the box horizontally, which it does, but it also adds a vertical scrollbar, which implies that it is affecting vertical overflow as well.

Comment: I've come up against the same problem. This question http://stackoverflow.com/q/6421966/586748 explains *why* it's happening this way, but I still haven't found a way to work around it. Have you had any luck?