# Horizontal Scroll - Mac Safari only

Tags: css

I'm getting a horizontal scroll, but only on Mac Safari. I can't replicate the issue elsewhere, and it's hard to troubleshoot (I usually use Firebug on Firefox for this).

The url is

```
http://getinjuryanswers.com
```

I would be happy to paste the code, but I'm not even sure what code to target.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not getting any horizontal scrolls in homepage

Comment: Did you try anything like hidden in your CSS body section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to outermost wrapper to fix scroll bar issue:

```
.site-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

To avoid this scroll bar issue I always use following structure and it never disturbs me..

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
             <header class="header"></header>
             <main class="main"></main>
             <footer class="footer"></footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    // and other necessary properties for your page.
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Not sure why that wasn't there before.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
html { overflow-x: hidden; }
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```