# Vertical Overflow on Body Element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, overflow, document-body

I am developing a site www.inquaress.com.

On every page the body element is overflowing in the y-direction, causing Chrome to render a double scrollbar (one for the Body element and one for the document). **How do I remove this scroll bar on the body element** and **why is the body element overflowing** - to my understanding, the body element should adapt to the contents within it?

Comment: `html, body` has `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: visible;` in `styles.css` line 84.

Comment: @showdev just added overflow-y: visible whilst experimenting. Originally, and I will set it as so now, overflow-y was not a defined property at all

Comment: I would like overflow-x remaining as hidden, but not have the effect of a vertical scrollbar on the body element. Surely that shouldn't be a side-effect of a property only affecting overflow in the x-direction?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand it myself. This post might shed some light on it: [Setting overflow-x: hidden adds a vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179831/setting-overflow-x-hidden-adds-a-vertical-scrollbar).

Comment: @showdev Thanks for that! Helpful link… fixed the issue by adding overflow-x: hidden; 'html' only